# How can I track my curl with xdebug

Tags: xdebug

I had tried to use Xdebug with sublime, it's work. And I want to track my curl code, for example:

I opened a URL `http://localhost:8001/test/show`, my breakpoint at the `test.php` file, it's work. And in the `test.php` I use `curl` to call `http://localhost:8002/api/show` and I want to add the breakpoint at `api.php` file, but it does not work on the `api.php`. How can I do it? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add XDEBUG_SESSION cookie to your curl request:

```
curl -i -X POST -d '{"some":"data"}' http://your-local-domain -b XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM
```

Optionally with `path` cookie:

```
curl --cookie "XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM;path=/;" localhost
```